# VPN comparison - on topic?

Tags: discussion

I fear that this would be off-topic on the main site, so ask here for clarification.

My IVPN subscription expires soon. I have been satisfied with the service and would normally just renew. However, I keep reading good things about NordVPN.

I see lots of comparison reviews, but :

- I suspect that many of them are just shills i.e xxxVPN sets up vepcompare.com and reviews xxxVPN very favourably and the competition not so
- I cannot be sure of the technical skills of the reviewers and do not myself possess the technical skills to know if they are competent; some seem to me like their “review” consisted of reading the VPN company’s website list of features

Would a comparison question be on-topic? Or a question asking about a competent and unbiased review site?

I am not looking for “best”. I can list features which are and are not, important to me.

Can I somehow put together  an on-topic question?

Answer (score 4):

While these questions as stated are not on-topic, you could change the focus to make it acceptable.

E.g. "What are the factors that I should consider when choosing a product/service", or "how can I evaluate a product".
These are on-topic, since they are product-agnostic and can last for a very long time (even if new technology might come out every few years). There are a few good examples of this on the site, and some exemplary answers that are still useful many years later.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate that. in this particular case, I don't have the knowledge to make a decision and was looking for a trustworthy party to make it for me. I will probably flip a coin ;-)

Answer (score 3):

No, none of those questions would be on topic. Questions for links and "what product/service does X?" all fall under the types of questions that either do not age well or become neverending as new answers could be added every day with no possibility of a single answer being possible.

Comment: I see what you mean, so will drop this here. On s/w recommendations, we try to obviate that by insisting on a detailed list of requirements, to get around the "which is best" angle, and just accept that next year their might be something which better meets those requirements.